# How to Tell If NIC supports Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

How do I know if my network card is capable of gigabit speeds under Windows 7?

Comment: Often times you can just tell by the name, what does it show under Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Device Manager, and go to the properties of your network card.

In the Advanced tab, find the Speed & Duplex setting.  The value of this should be "Auto Negotation", however, in the dropdown there is a list of speeds the card can support.  If 1Gbps is in the list, the card supports gigabit.

[image]

Leave the card set to auto-negotiate.

Comment: This might also be titled "Link Speed & Duplex"

Comment: This setting does not exist in my wireless card.